# Mudar tema da pagina em java

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho esse código em java que é usado para mudar o tema do meu site

```
function change_mode() {

    var app = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];

    if (localStorage.lightMode == "dark") {
        localStorage.lightMode = "light";
        app.setAttribute("class", "light");
    } else {
        localStorage.lightMode = "dark";
        app.setAttribute("class", "dark");
    }
    console.log("lightMode = " + localStorage.lightMode);
```

}

```
$('.tos-nav-btn').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){

            }else {
                let getFor = $(this).attr('for');
                $('.tos-nav-btn').removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                $('.tos-tab').removeClass('active');
                $('#'+ getFor +'.tos-tab').addClass('active')

            }
});
    
$('.home-ss-tab').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).find('.ss-tab-content').slideToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.home-ss-tab').removeClass('active');
        $('.home-ss-tab > .ss-tab-content').slideUp(200);
        $(this).find('.ss-tab-content').slideToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Então no meu header fica esse código

```
<script>
     var app = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
     if (localStorage.lightMode == "dark") {
        app.setAttribute("class", "dark");
     }
  </script>
```

Tudo funciona certinho, só que o tema padrão que vem é light, e eu queria deixar o padrão dark, não sei muito de java então já tentei diversas coisas e nada vai [tem um botão que faz mudar]

Answer (score -2):

Esse código que fica no header altera para o código abaixo e veja se resolve.

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     var app = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
     if (localStorage.lightMode == "dark") {
        app.setAttribute("class", "dark");
     }
  })
</script>
```

Como você está carregando o script no header, a tag `body` ainda não foi carregada (deve até estar exibindo erros no console). No código acima adicionei um evento na página para executar os comandos apenas quando todo DOM estiver carregado.

[Evento DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)